# 'member_descriptor' object cannot be interpreted as an integer when looping through the timedelta.day

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-views

Am trying to filter through the number of days a users birthday is coming up. but whenever i filter through users upcoming birthdays for some reason I keep hitting this error 'member_descriptor' object cannot be interpreted as an integer, I have looked on stack overflow to find a solution but so far all seems not to fix my current challenge. I think the error stems from the for loop with deltatime.days, How best can i loop through the days in deltatime.days ?

```
        
def upcoming_birthdays(request):
    birthdays_today = []
    friend_list = FriendList.objects.get(user=request.user)
    #get all people with birthday today
    for p in  friend_list.friends.all():
        if p.isBirthdayToday():
            birthdays_today.append(p)

    #get and format today's date
    today = date.today()
    suffix = _getSuffix(today)
    today_date = '{}{} {}'.format(today.day, suffix, today.strftime("%B"))
    # All upcoming birthdays
    friend_list = FriendList.objects.get(user=request.user)
    birth_list = friend_list.friends.all().distinct()
    today = date.today()
    upcoming_date_list = []
    upcoming_date_list.extend(list(birth_list.filter(birth_date__month=today.month, birth_date__day=today.day)))
    next_day = today + timedelta(days=1)
    # this where am looping through the days for upcoming birthdays
    for day in range(0, (timedelta.days)):
        upcoming_date_list.extend(list(birth_list.filter(birth_date__month=next_day.month, birth_date__day=next_day.day, birth_date__isnull=True)))
        next_day = next_day + timedelta(days=1) 

    #return template plus context
    context = {
        'birthdays_today': birthdays_today,
        'today_date': today_date,
        'upcoming_date_list': upcoming_date_list,
    }
    return render(request, 'account/birthdays.html',context)
```

here is the traceback exception

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Umar\Desktop\dreams\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\Umar\Desktop\dreams\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Umar\Desktop\dreams\feed\views.py", line 325, in upcoming_birthdays
    for day in range(0, (timedelta.days)):
TypeError: 'member_descriptor' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

Comment: What did you mean by `timedelta.days`?

Comment: timedelta.days is not an integer, so it can not be casted

Comment: Okay so what do you suggest i do in other to loop through the days ?

Comment: @YevgeniyKosmak timedelta.days are the number of days in the month that am looping through for the upcoming birthdays >.